# How to embedd sql in Java application?

Tags: java, mysql

I have created an application in Java using eclipse and MySQL using Xampp.I have used a connector.jar to link the same.
How can I create an exe that contains the database(without having to install xampp) and run it on a system where there is no java or sql installed?

Comment: seriously, running java class without JRE ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Excelsior JET compiler.

Also MySQL is not need to install on client, just include connector jar in exe. Client should able to connect server with firewall on necessary port.